# Properties of the "girth function" of a matroid

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorial-optimization, matroid-theory

Given an independent set representation of a matroid $M=(E,\mathcal{F})$ its ``rank function'' $r$ defined on the powerset of $E$ is:
$$
\forall X \subseteq E, \quad r(X) = \max_{Y \subseteq X}\{|Y|, Y \in \mathcal{F}\}.
$$

This is well-known, of course, and $r$ is submodular.

Now I've been wondering for some time what happens if we define the ``girth function'' in a similar way, i.e. the girth of a subset $X \subseteq E$ is the size of the minimum circuit inside $X$ or $\infty$ otherwise. Formally:

$$
 \forall X \subseteq E, \quad g(X) = \cases{
\min_{Y \subseteq X}\{|Y|, Y \notin \mathcal{F}\}, \\
\infty, X \in \mathcal{F}.
}
$$

Basically, I am interested in the girth of $M$ which is known to be HP-Hard. But I was hoping for some variant of submodularity which could be leveraged for an approximation algorithm.

Does this make any sense?